# Why, in Web API 2, raising an HttpResponseException the HttpActionExecutedContext.Exception property is null?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing one Web API 2 web service. I'm using an ActionFilter with following code:

```
public abstract class BaseActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception; <-- If I throw an HttpResponseException this property is NULL.
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

This is the code of my custom Exception:

```
public class ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException : HttpResponseException
{
    private static string standardMsg = "Exception during creation of resource. The resource already exist.";

    public ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException() : base(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
    {
        this.Response.Content = new StringContent(standardMsg);
    }

    public ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException(string errorCode, string errorMessage) : base(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
    {
        JsonUtilities jsonUtilities = new JsonUtilities();
        var obj = new { errorCode = errorCode, errorMessage = errorMessage };
        string message = jsonUtilities.Serialize(obj);

        this.Response.Content = new StringContent(message, System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json");
    }
}
```

And this is my action's code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public void Create(MyDto datas)
{
    try
    {
        companyService.Create(datas);
    }
    catch (CodeAlreadyExistException ex)
    {
        throw new ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException(ex.ErrorCode, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (FiscalCodeAlreadyExistException ex)
    {
        throw new ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException(ex.ErrorCode, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (VatAlreadyExistException ex)
    {
        throw new ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException(ex.ErrorCode, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is this: If I rise one ResourceAlreadyExistResponseException the property actionExecutedContext.Exception is null, but if I raise one generic exeption the propety is correctly set.

Can you help me please?

Thanks